# I am able to parse the log file but not getting output in correct format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parse a text file using python. I am using split command, to split the line at :,=. I am able to parse it successfully but I want the output as below.

Input:

```
customer1:124  
clientID:1   
Error=1  
customer2:125  
clientID:1   
Error=2  
customer3:126  
clientID:1  
Error=3
```

Desired output:

```
Customer | Error  
customer1   1  
customer2   2  
customer3   3
```

Here is my code:

```
import re

with open('logfile','r') as log_data:
    for line in log_data:
        if line.startswith("customer") | line.startswith("Error"):
            res = re.split(':|=',line)
            print(res)
```

Output which I am getting is

```
['customer1', '123\n']
['Error', '1\n']
['customer1', '124\n']
['Error', '2\n']
['customer1', '125\n']
['Error', '3\n']
['customer1', '126\n']
['Error', '4\n']
```

Comment: You should use `or` for logical-or; `|` is bitwise-or.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Looks like you did not understand my question, I am able to split the input successfully. The problem what I have is with only printing the output.

Comment: Yes; and by concatenating lists into strings, as described in the duplicate that I linked for you, you will produce the output you need to print.